# Given an integer, your task is to find another integer such that their bitwise XOR is maximum

Tags: max, xor

Assume you have a binary representation of a number of length n as x="0100" and the task is to find another number y=? of length n whose k bits should be set so that x XOR y is maximum.

Eg: x="01010" and k=1 given
o/p: y should be 10000

Here is my code:But its not working..

```
 public static String maxXorValue(String x, int k) {
// Write your code here
    int arr[]=new int[x.length()];
    String ans="";
    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
        arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(x.charAt(i)));
    }
    if(k==0){
        return x;
    }
    else{
    int q=0;
    while(q<arr.length){
       if(k>0){
        if(arr[q]==0){
            k--;
            ans+="1";
            q++;
        }
        else{
            ans+="0";
            q++;
        }
    }
    else{
        ans+="0";
        q++;
    }
    
}
    return ans;
}
```

}

}

Comment: where there is a 0 you put a 1, and where there is 1 you put a 0, doesn't seem that difficult

Comment: A hint: the 1) the largest number of N bits is 1 repeated N times, 2) for any bit `b`: `b XOR ~b == 1`.

Comment: The restriction that you must have `k` bits set in `y` is nontrivial. Current comments don't address that.

Comment: @Nandita Sahu, I think more examples would be helpful. I originally read it as "at most k bits set" but perhaps you mean "exactly k bits set"? If x="11111" and k="2", is the desired y="00000" or y="00011"?

Answer (score 0):

**The Algorithm**

I could not find a clever mathematical solution, but one (tedious) method to compute the answer:

1. Start by taking a candidate solution as y=0. Set `num_bits_set` to 0.
2. (starting from the left) at each position where the bit value of `x` is a 0, set the value of `y` in that position to `1` and increment `num_bits_set`. Break from this step if `num_bits_set==k` at any point
3. Iff `num_bits_set < k` after finishing step (2), take `remaining=k-num_bits_set`. Start from the right and at each position where the bit value of `x` is a 1, set the value of `y` in that position to 1 also and decrement `remaining`. If at any point `remaining==0` break from this step
4. Return `y`

**As to why this works:**

"1111..." (n bits) is maximal for an `n` bit binary number. Assume to start that `y=0`, then `x^y=x^0=x`.

Then setting any bit in `y` which causes a 0 bit in `x^y` to flip to a 1 increases `x^y`. Let's call this an "increasing change"
Setting any bit in `y` which causes a 1 bit in `x^y` to flip to a 0 decreases `x^y`. Let's call this a "decreasing change"

We set the `k` bits to maximize `x^y` using a greedy algorithm, first going over all the "increasing changes" in descending order of importance (take biggest increase first, take second biggest second, etc.). If we run out of increasing changes, we start making decreasing changes, but in increasing order of importance this time (i.e., make the smallest change possible if you have to decrease `x^y`).

Since all of the bits contribute independently to the total sum, this greedy algorithm will definitely arrive at the optimal result.

**Examples**

## Case 1

```
n = 5, k = 1
x = 01010, y = 00000, x^y=01010, num_bits_set = 0
# Start from the left, and every place where x = 0, set y=1 and increment num_bits_set
x = 01010, y = 10000, x^y=11010, num_bits_set = 1
    ^          ^
y = 10000
Done.

# y ^ x = 11010 Which is maximal
```

## Case 2

```
n = 5, k = 1
x = 01010, y = 00000, x^y=01010, num_bits_set = 0
# Start from the left, and every place where x = 0, set y=1 and increment num_bits_set
x = 01010, y = 10000, x^y=11010, num_bits_set = 1
    ^          ^
x = 01010, y = 10100, x^y=11110, num_bits_set = 2
      ^          ^
x = 01010, y = 10101, x^y=11111, num_bits_set = 3
        ^          ^
# num_bits_set < k, so continue with leftward pass
x = 01010, y = 10101, x^y=11111, remaining = 1
x = 01010, y = 10111, x^y=11101, remaining = 0
       ^          ^           
y = 10111
Done.

# y ^ x = 11101 which is maximal
```

If you wanted to implement this, I find working with strings to be easier/more intuitive (but probably also slower) than working with integers and twiddling bits.